# In javascript, text sometimes displays and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, css, html

```
var enemies = [
                {
                    "name" : "Green Slime",
                    "health" : 30,
                    "attacks" : [
                                {
                                    "name" : "Bounce",
                                    "damage" : 10,
                                    "selfDamage" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "name" : "Self Destruct",
                                    "damage" : 30,
                                    "selfDamage" : 30
                                }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Blue Slime",
                    "health" : 60,
                    "attacks" : [
                                {
                                    "name" : "Bounce",
                                    "damage" : 20,
                                    "selfDamage" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "name" : "Shine",
                                    "damage" : 30,
                                    "selfDamage" : 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "name" : "Self Destruct",
                                    "damage" : 60,
                                    "selfDamage" : 60
                                }
                    ]
                }
 ];
var enemyText = " Has decided to battle you!";
function $(input, type) {
    if (type == "id") {
        return document.getElementById(input);
    }
    else {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(input);
    }
}
function Fight() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * enemies.length);
    var enemy = enemies[parseInt(a)]
    var enemyName = enemies[parseInt(a)].name;
    $("FightText", "id").innerHTML = "A " + enemyName + enemyText;
    while (enemy.health > 0) {
        var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * enemy.attacks.length)
        var attack = enemy.attacks[b]
        $("FightText", "id").innerHTML += "<br>" + enemyName + " Used " + attack.name + "! <i>Dealt " + attack.damage + " damage</i>";
        enemy.health -= attack.selfDamage;
    }
}
```

So when I run the `Fight` function repeatively, it sometimes will not display the attacks that the enemy used.
As in, it might just display `A Blue Slime Has decided to battle you!` instead of actually saying the attacks it used.
Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

***Do note that I have a tendency to ask questions that are obvious to others, so, yeah. this one might be obvious.***

Comment: Give us an [MCVE]. Remove lines of code not pertinent to this question to start.

Comment: A guess, it might have to do with the enemies' health not getting reset in the while loop of  your Fight() function

Comment: But it does it only *sometimes*, not all the time

Comment: You might want to consider learning a bit about debugging JavaScript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript.

You could, for example, add a break point before the loop and check the enemies array data. As @kingdaro said, you'll find that the enemy you're fighting has zero health. This is why it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're updating your enemy templates, rather than new instances.
Eventually, they all run out of health and as soon as that happens you never step into `while (enemy.health > 0) {`.

More importantly: before coding any further, you should first learn about debugging javascript code. Debugging is possible in any browser and most development environments. For example: [Debugging in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Comment: How to go about this?

Comment: There are multiple options, but you might want to start learning about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS
Just replace "Person" by "Enemy" :)